# .ova file to run in a Docker container

Tags: bash, docker, vmware, tar, raw

I have a custom image that I’m trying to run in a Docker container.

Here are my steps following this post from here to cover to .ova to docker container
https://andygreen.phd/2022/01/26/converting-vm-images-to-docker-containers/)

- Took a .ova file  (We normally use this file in VMWare)
- Converted it into a .raw file
- Took that .raw file and mounted it
- Created a tarball
- Imported that tarball into a docker image

Command to create the image:

`docker import fileName.tar.gz <container name>:1.0`

Command to turn it on:

`docker run -i -t <image id> /bin/bash`

Then:

`docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown. ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled`

The problem is at the last step. I am not sure about the last command because it is a web server that gets automatically spun up when you start it in VMWare so I was wondering if anyone knows how I could approach it?

I think I need to know the command that VMWare uses to start the image. Any advice/support is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You're asking Docker to start `/bin/bash` inside the container, but apparently that command doesn't exist. Since you have the tar file handy, you can inspect it to see what commands *do* exist.

Comment: I inspected it and nothing came up. 
I used the command tar `-tzf myFile.tar.gz`